# Access old deleted question

Tags: support

How can I access the Question, my friend got the Tumbleweed Badge for here?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed?userid=3448577

Comment: A note below "earned this badge" line in the link _(post deleted or otherwise unavailable)_. You should have at-least 10,000 reputation to see that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend deleted the question, so you cannot see it.<sup>†</sup> By design, deleted questions are not available for viewing.

*He* can still see it, and he can find a link to it [in his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/3448577) (for up to 90 days after deletion). If deleting it was a mistake, then he should be able to find it and undelete it.

As for why he has a badge for a deleted question, it is because badges are not generally revoked. He still earned the badge legitimately, even if he has since deleted the question.

<sub><sup>†</sup> Until you earn at least 10,000 reputation on Stack Overflow, which will allow you to see deleted posts for moderation purposes.</sub>

Comment: But he didn't delete it and the question maybe still open for him. Can you undelete it pĺease?

Comment: He *did* delete it, on May 14th at 14:31. You have the direct link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572226/jquery-greasemonkey-ajax-gets-no-answer. Send it to him and tell him to undelete it.

Comment: now he just logged out and doesn't know his email anymore, his account now is http://askubuntu.com/users/294881/user294881 can you tell his email provider? is it a gmail address? Or was it moved to superuser?

Comment: Maybe it was this? http://superuser.com/questions/603373/how-do-i-reverse-proxy-etherpad-lite-with-nginx-to-a-subdirectory but that was "deleted by community" And it sais: "A moderator has deleted this post and it can't be undeleted", why? This question is still there for him

Comment: You asked about a question on Stack Overflow. Now you're talking about other sites that have nothing to do with anything. I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: It seems like that question was first merged to superuser and then deleted by the communuty without reason. He didn't delete it himself

Comment: I can find *no* evidence that it was ever migrated. I can't see the Super User question that you linked to, since I don't have 10k on that site. If what you say is true, I guess you'll need a community team member to help. One will see this question eventually.

Comment: OK: [Find out, why a question was deleted](http://meta.superuser.com/q/8112)

Comment: @CodyGray it's the auto prune delete script running.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year

Comment: @Sathya I don't think so. As far as I know, that script has them deleted by the *Community* user, not the original poster. (Edit: Err, that may be the case for Super User. I was talking about the Stack Overflow question. Lots of questions here, seemingly unrelated.)

Comment: @CodyGray it was deleted by Community (the [su] question in question) http://superuser.com/posts/603373/revisions